# useQuery used in custom hook returns a response with type useQueryResults<unknown, unknown>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-query

I have the following custom hook called `useGetQuery`

```
type Props = Parameters<typeof useQuery>;

const useGetQuery = (...params: Props) => {
    const useQueryResults = useQuery(params);

    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            useQueryResults.refetch();
        }, [useQueryResults])
    );

    return useQueryResults;
};
```

Which I then call in `useGetScreen` like this:

```
export const useGetScreen = (screenId: string) => {
    return useGetQuery(['getScreen', { screenId }], () => getScreen(screenId), { staleTime: 0 });
};
```

And `useGetScreen` is called like this

```
const { data: screen } = useGetScreen('vegetables');
```

My problem is that in this case, article has a type of `unknown` and I can't figure out why is this happening. My guess is that I have to somehow type what is being returned by useFocusRefetchQuery. Before I implemented the custom hook, Typescript automatically inferred the return type of `useQuery`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recall typescript infering anything from the GQL request string, in my experience you need to provide `useQuery` the expected output and input (variables) types as mentioned [here in details](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing). The `useQuery` signature is as follow:

```
useQuery<TData = any, TVariables = OperationVariables>
```

In your case you would have to add both `Props` and your article type, say `Article`:

```
import { gql, QueryHookOptions, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

const GET_ARTICLE_QUERY = gql`
  query getArticle {
    article: {
      id,
      articleId,
      articleName,
    }
  }
`

interface ArticleContent {
  __typename: "Article";
  id: string;
  articleId: string;
  articleName: string;
}

interface Article {
  article: ArticleContent | null;
}

interface ArticleInput {
  articleId: string;
}

const useArticleQuery = (options: QueryHookOptions = {}) => {
    return useQuery<Article, ArticleInput>(GET_ARTICLE_QUERY);
}
```

I think its also a good idea to keep the options (`QueryHookOptions`) in here so you can use your hook in different contexts.

You can use a tool like [Graphql code generator](https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen) to automatically generate the static types `Article` and `ArticleInput` for you (based on your schema and your JS `gql` requests).

If you want to have a generic hook for several `useQuery` that all look the same (for example they all use `useFocusEffect`), you will have to do something like this:

```
function useFocusRefetchQuery<TData, TVariables>(){
    const useQueryResults = useQuery<TData, TVariables>();
    // ...
}
```

This way you can use `useFocusRefetchQuery` instead of `useQuery`, but I really think you will have to pass both the input/output types, which means in the previous example you would have:

```
const useArticleQuery = (options: QueryHookOptions = {}) => {
    return useFocusRefetchQuery<Article, ArticleInput>(GET_ARTICLE_QUERY);
}
```